# Create route for every controller of index method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I'm developing a school management system in laravel. I have many controllers like

**controller staff in method index**

```
class controllerstaff extends controller {
    public function index{
    //here process of staff data
    }
}

//this controller have `Route::get('/', 'controllerstaff@index');
```

**and other controller**

```
class controllerstudent extends controller {
    public function index{
    //here process of student data
    }
}

//this controller have Route::get('/', 'controllerstudent@index');
```

As above does not work properly.

Any one can tell me how to create route for every controller of index method. If we crate many route file then how operate it and how access in controller and form action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create same urls for each route. For each route you need to have different url, for example:

```
Route::get('/staff', 'controllerstaff@index');
Route::get('/students', 'controllerstudent@index');
```

You should also name your controllers rather `StudentController` and not `controllerstudent`. You might also consider looking at [Routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing) before creating code - I believe it might be the right way ;)